# Cut a bounding box using numpy meshgrid python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, polygon, bounding-box

I want to create a bounding box out of the following dimensions using meshgrid but just not able to get the right box.

My parent dimensions are `x = 0 to 19541` and `y = 0 to 14394`. Out of that, I want to cut a box from x' = 4692 to 12720 and `y' = 4273 to 10117`.

However, I am not getting the right bounds. Could someone please help me here?

```
from matplotlib.path import Path

        xmin, xmax = 4692, 12720
        ymin, ymax = 4273, 10117
        sar_ver = [(4692, 10117), (12720, 10117), (12658, 4274), (4769, 4273), (4692, 10117)]

        x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1), np.arange(ymin, ymax + 1))
        shx = x
        x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
        points = np.vstack((x, y)).T

        path = Path(sar_ver)
        grid = path.contains_points(points)

        grid.shape = shx.shape # 5845 X 8029

        print grid
```

UPDATE: This is what I tried and I am close to what I want but not exactly. I want to change the original origin from 0 to the image's surrounding box as shown in expected output.

The updated code that I am using is this

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
    nx, ny = 16886, 10079
    sar_ver = [(16886, 1085), (15139, 2122), (14475, 5226), (8419, 5601), (14046, 6876), (14147, 10079), (16816, 3748), (16886, 1085)]
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny))
    x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
    points = np.vstack((x,y)).T
    path = Path(sar_ver)
    grid = path.contains_points(points)

    grid.shape = (10079, 16886)
    grid = np.multiply(grid,255)
    int_grid = grid.astype(np.uint8)
    grid_img = Image.fromarray(int_grid)
    grid_img.save('grid_image.png')  # ACTUAL OUTPUT IMAGE WITH ORIGIN NOT SHIFTED
```

Input geom: [image]

Expected output is this: Doesn't matter if the image is rotated the other way round but will be a cherry on top if its aligned correctly.
[image]

However I am getting right now this so my ACTUAL OUTPUT from the updated code posted is this:

[image]

So I want to shift the origin around the box.

BOUNDING BOX PROBLEM DETAILS AFTER GETTING THE MASK: This code comes after the line posted in the second update `grid_img.save('grid_image.png')  # ACTUAL OUTPUT IMAGE WITH ORIGIN NOT SHIFTED`

Here `im` is the matrix of the actual image. What should be the x-y min, max of `im` to have the same shape as mask and multiply both of them to get pixel values and the rest cancelled out with 0s.

```
        img_x = 19541 # 0 - 19541
        img_y = 14394 # 0 - 14394
        im = np.fromfile(binary_file_path, dtype='>f4')
        im = np.reshape(im.astype(np.float32), (img_x, img_y))
        im = im[:10079, :16886]
        bb_list = np.multiply(grid, im)
        # slice and dice
        slice_rows = np.any(bb_list, axis=1)
        slice_cols = np.any(bb_list, axis=0)
        ymin, ymax = np.where(slice_rows)[0][[0, -1]]
        xmin, xmax = np.where(slice_cols)[0][[0, -1]]
        answer = bb_list[ymin:ymax + 1, xmin:xmax + 1]
        # convert to unit8
        int_ans = answer.astype(np.uint8)
        fin_img = Image.fromarray(int_ans)
        fin_img.save('test_this.jpeg')
```

My GOAL is to cut out a polygon of a given geom out of a given image. So I am taking the mask out of that polygon and then using that mask to cut the same out of the original image. So multiplying mask's 1's and 0's with the pixel values in the image to just get 1*pixel values.

I tried the following to cut out the actual image to have the same dimensions so that I can multiply `np.multiply(im, mask)` but it didn't work as image's shape is not cut into same shape as mask's. I tried your min and max below but didn't work!

```
im = im[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
ipdb> im.shape
(5975, 8994)
ipdb> mask.shape
(8994, 8467)
```

Clearly I cannot multiple mask and im now.

Comment: could you provide a working example? `sar_ver` definition is missing

Comment: @filippo sorry about that. added now.

Comment: The "origin" is at (0,0). You cannot shift the origin because that is how "origin" is defined. But the rest of the image is purely determined by the points you feed in and the grid you produce. So choosing different points and/or a different grid will produce a different figure. E.g. if you subtract 6000 from your input points' x coordinates, the shape would move to roughly half way to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it almost right in the first attempt, in the second one you're building a `meshgrid` for the full image while you just want the shape mask, don't you?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib import patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image

sar_ver = [(16886, 1085), (15139, 2122), (14475, 5226), (8419, 5601),
           (14046, 6876), (14147, 10079), (16816, 3748), (16886, 1085)]

path = Path(sar_ver)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.asarray(path.get_extents(), dtype=int).ravel()

x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
points = np.transpose((x.ravel(), y.ravel()))

mask = path.contains_points(points)
mask = mask.reshape(x.shape).T

img = Image.fromarray((mask * 255).astype(np.uint8))
img.save('mask.png')


# plot shape and mask for debug purposes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
gs.update(wspace=0.2, hspace= 0.01)

ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)

ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.imshow(mask, origin='lower')

plt.savefig("shapes.png", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

It produces the mask:

[image: mask]

And also plots both the mask and the path for debugging purposes:

[image: shapes]

The different orientation comes from the different origin position in `matplotlib` plots and images, but it should be trivial enough to change it the way you want.

**EDIT after latest question edits**

Here's an updated script that takes an image, generates a mask for your path and cuts it out. I'm using a dummy image and scaling down shapes a bit so they're easier to work with.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib import patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import skimage.transform
import skimage.data

from PIL import Image

sar_ver = np.asarray([(16886, 1085), (15139, 2122), (14475, 5226), (8419, 5601),
           (14046, 6876), (14147, 10079), (16816, 3748), (16886, 1085)])

# reshape into smaller path for faster debugging
sar_ver = sar_ver // 20

# create dummy image
img = skimage.data.chelsea()
img = skimage.transform.rescale(img, 2)

# matplotlib path
path = Path(sar_ver)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.asarray(path.get_extents(), dtype=int).ravel()

# create a mesh grid of the shape of the final mask
x, y = np.mgrid[:img.shape[1], :img.shape[0]]
# mesh grid to points
points = np.vstack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())).T

# mask for the point included in the path
mask = path.contains_points(points)
mask = mask.reshape(x.shape).T

# plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
gs.update(wspace=0.2, hspace= 0.2)

# image + patch
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax.imshow(img)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor="None", edgecolor="cyan", lw=3)
ax.add_patch(patch)

# mask
ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.imshow(mask)

# filter image with mask
ax = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax.imshow(img * mask[..., np.newaxis])

# remove mask from image
ax = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax.imshow(img * ~mask[..., np.newaxis])

# plt.show()
plt.savefig("shapes.png", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

[image: cat]

Comment: I started doing the second approach bcoz after getting the mask, I wanted to get the bounding box out of actual image. Please check my update where I have added the code after wards. I am really sorry for continuous edits.

Comment: the code that I added recently where `im` is the matrix of the actual image. what should be the x-y min, max of that to have the same shape as mask and multiply it.

Comment: @Atihska I'm not sure I'm following you anymore... in the second edit you first say *expected output is this* and my answer reproduces that exactly. Now you want the full mask and not the just the bounding box? Just change `(xmin, ymin)` to `(0,0)` and `(ymin, ymax)` to `your_original_image.shape`

Comment: I am really sorry if I confused you. What you gave is great, but after that I need this shaped mask from the original image. I don't want full mask. The mask that I have got from your code, I want to multiply with the original image. The original image shape is different from the mask. My question is what are my original image's x,y min and max so that it is same as that of mask and I can cut it.

Comment: Let me know if I need to post another question. I will accept this answer for the mask part and post another with the extension problem. Again apologies!

Comment: @Atihska the shape of the mask is given by the `meshgrid` you build. So I you just need `np.mgrid[0:original_img.shape[0], 0:original_img.shape[1]]`

Comment: @Atihska no idea, that's your choice, the question is a quite a bit confused at this moment but I think the solution is simpler than you believe. But again I'm not so sure anymore I'm following :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170976/discussion-between-atihska-and-filippo).

Comment: original_img.shape = 14394, 19541. If I do mgrid on original_image, I don't get how can I multiply the mask with it which has different shape (8994, 8467)

Comment: Basically, I need to cut that mask from the image.

Comment: @Atihska see the edit please, let me know if you open another question (I believe you should), and I'll move my answer there

Answer (score 0):

I tried the open cv2 library and it appears to be faster than meshgrid or mgrid on large images. Posting opencv2 solution:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path

sar_ver = np.array([[[1688, 108], [1513, 212], [1447, 522], [841, 560], [1404, 687], [1414, 1007], [1681, 374], [1688, 108]]] , 'int32')
print sar_ver.shape
mask=np.zeros((1439, 1954))
cv2.fillPoly(mask, sar_ver, 255)

sar_ver = np.asarray([(1688, 108), (1513, 212), (1447, 522), (841, 560), (1404, 687), (1414, 1007), (1681, 374), (1688, 108)])
path = Path(sar_ver)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.asarray(path.get_extents(), dtype=int).ravel()

plt.imshow(mask[ymin:ymax+1, xmin:xmax+1])
plt.show()
```

Also, posting mgrid solution helped by Filippo above and on online chat:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib.path import Path
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
sar_ver = np.asarray([(1518, 2024), (2018, 2024), (1518, 2524), (1518, 2024)])

imag = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(imag, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = img.shape

path = Path(sar_ver)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.asarray(path.get_extents(), dtype=int).ravel()

# create a mesh grid of the shape of the final mask
x, y = np.mgrid[:w, :h]
# mesh grid to points
points = np.vstack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())).T

# mask for the point included in the path
mask = path.contains_points(points)
mask = mask.reshape(x.shape).T

im = np.array(img)
bb = np.multiply(im, mask)[ymin:ymax+1, xmin:xmax+1]
# saving image or we can do  plt.show
int_ans = bb.astype(np.uint8)
fin = Image.fromarray(int_ans)
fin.save('crop_test.png')
```