# How to get all pixel coordinates in an area specified in an image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

The area in image is defined by 4 coordinates `x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4` and  I want to retrieve all the pixel coordinates `x,y` inside that area.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a rectangular shape, you can use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) to generate a coordinate matrix for the points between your top left and bottom right corners.

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
```

and convert them to a bidimensional array of coordinates with

```
np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))
```

---

**EDIT:** arbitrary shapes

As Mark Setchell pointed out, there is nothing in your question that talks about rectangular shapes.

If you want to list all the points inside an arbitrary path, not necessarily of 4 vertices, you can use `contains_points()` from `matplotlib` [`Path`](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html).

Here's some code derived from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50313662/5629339)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path

import skimage.data

# path vertex coordinates
vertices = np.asarray([(100, 100),
                       (300,  80),
                       (350, 200),
                       ( 60, 150)])

# create dummy image
img = skimage.data.chelsea()

# from vertices to a matplotlib path
path = Path(vertices)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.asarray(path.get_extents(), dtype=int).ravel()

# create a mesh grid for the whole image, you could also limit the
# grid to the extents above, I'm creating a full grid for the plot below
x, y = np.mgrid[:img.shape[1], :img.shape[0]]
# mesh grid to a list of points
points = np.vstack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())).T

# select points included in the path
mask = path.contains_points(points)
path_points = points[np.where(mask)]

# reshape mask for display
img_mask = mask.reshape(x.shape).T

# now lets plot something to convince ourselves everything works
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# masked image
ax.imshow(img * img_mask[..., None])
# a random sample from path_points
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(path_points.shape[0]), 200)
ax.scatter(path_points[idx, 0], path_points[idx, 1], alpha=0.3, color='cyan')
```

[image: chelsea masked]

Comment: Are you assuming the shape is rectangular? Is the shape rectangular @vijay ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell duh, you're right, I am... let's wait what OP says I'll try to make it more general... iirc there was a matplotlib question to convert a generic path to a list of points

Comment: Yes its a rectangle, but not necessarily a horizontal one, it is an oriented rectangle, that cant be defined by just two corner points, but by all 4 points

Comment: @vijay what about my edit? That should work for any closed polygon with 3 or more vertices