# How to extract pixels of specified coordinates from image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am extracting some pixels from an image using the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('random.png')
targets = np.array([[111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333]], dtype=np.uint8)
targeted = []
for x, y in targets:
    targeted.append(img[x, y])
```

Is there a more pythonic or vectorized method to do it in one line instead of this `for` loop?

Comment: You haven't defined `r`

Comment: What is `img.shape` ?

Comment: does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812749/how-to-get-all-pixel-coordinates-in-an-area-specified-in-an-image-in-python?

Comment: @fountainhead, I just edited the question.  The image shape can be any.

Comment: What is `img.ndim` ?

Comment: Here you go.  `img.ndim = 3`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for (in the place of the `for` loop):

```
targeted = img[tuple(targets.T)].tolist()
```

If you don't want to convert into a list:

```
targeted = img[tuple(targets.T)]
```

Comment: I want to acquired all pixels specified by `targets`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  How can I calculated the average pixel value from the acquired value?  Assume I don't need to use `tolist()`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by average pixel value. Please illustrate with a sample `targeted`

Comment: `targeted` will now be an `ndarray` of size ABCx3 (ABC = number of specified pixels).  I wish to find the average color `[a b c]` from the acquired pixels.

Comment: Assume `targeted` = `[[100,50,25], [10, 20, 30]]`. What is your expected output for "average pixel value" ?

Comment: [55, 35, 27].  I wanna know how that can be done.

Comment: In that case `np.mean(targeted, axis=0)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I got the output after renaming r to targets .
It could be because your image object is None.
Can you check :

1. Whether path/image filename is correct
2. Whether the image has a size of more than 111 (which is the minimum location)(

Comment: I want to know if there is a better way.  Assume all the specified coordinates are valid.